# Does .net framework support Assembly redirection using policy file across different version 1.1 & 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net

There is need to support legacy applications which are built in .net 1.1 framework. So i have interface assembly (ex. : ISample.dll version 1.4.0.0) also built in .net 1.1 framework, latest implementation of this interface assembly (ex. :Sample.dll 1.4.1.0) is built in .net 3.5 framework and policy redirection assembly( policy.1.4.Sample.dll) are also built in  .net 3.5 framework.

I tried this it is not working. so question is, does .net framework support assembly redirection across different version 1.1, 3.5 or others ?

Comment: The 1.1 version of the CLR cannot load assemblies compiled with 3.5 tools.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know a higher .NET version should support assemblies compiled for older .NET versions. The other way around could be a little bit complicated. You may follow the approach of CLR-hosting, by using the native CLR hosting interface of mscore and wrapping it backwards to your .NET1.1 application. But this still requires Version 3.5 installed on your system. For more information look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx

But notice that this is really really inperformant and uncomfortable, because you have to wrap it back, and you have to wrap the used 3.5 assembly.

Otherwise I will have to say. "No there is no way (i know of) to do that."